# How to Create Cronjob in NestJs Kubernetes cluster so at a given time only one pod job get executed

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, cron, nestjs

**Scenario** : A repo of NestJs is executing a cron job for sending messages to subscribers as per cron expression. Scenario is running fine when only one instance is running.

**Problem** : Multiple email received by subscriber when *multiple* instance(pods) are running in K8 cluster.

**Solution Looking for** : Without database, or separate out service can we do something with "**K8s**" ***yaml*** so that at a given point of time only one pod is executing the cron job.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `concurrencyPolicy` option in **cronjob** on the kubernetes cluster. This option helps to run only one task at a time. Even though multiple triggers are requested for a job, it will skip the triggers until the execution of the current task is done.

In your case you need to set the option to `Forbid` as shown below, so that it will make sure to execute only request at a time.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid    #Enabling the concurrencyPolicy
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: demo
            image: busybox:1.28
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

**Note:** Using the `concurrencyPolicy` field to limit the number of pods might affect the performance of a job, as it may result in longer execution time.

You can also limit the creation of a number of pods by using the `parallelism` field in the job. For more information refer to this [parallelism](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#parallel-jobs).

For more detailed information refer to this [official k8's](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy) documentation